# ExtJS : Date picker 'monthspinner' picker not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, extjs

Date picker with monthspinner is not working in Chrome. But works perfectly fine in IE.

```
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'combo',
                    queryMode: 'local',
                    triggerAction: 'all',
                    forceSelection: true,
                    emptyText: 'Date Range Type',
                    fieldLabel: 'RSP Topic Range',
                    editable: false,      
                    hidden: false,
                    disabled: false,
                    name: 'dateTopicRangeType',
                    displayField: 'name',
                    valueField: 'value',
                    value: 'date_range',
                    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                        fields: ['name', 'value'],
                        data: [
                            {name : 'RSP Month',  value:'rsp_month'},
                           ]
                    })
                },{
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    name: 'fs_topic_rsp_month',
                    filterGroup: 'topic_range',
                    hidden: true,
                    disabled: true,
                    items: [{
                        fieldLabel: 'Month',
                        anchor: '98%',
                        labelWidth: 120,
                        labelAlign: 'right',
                        editable: false,  
                        allowBlank: false,
                        width: 320,
                        name: 'topic_rsp_month',
                        xtype: 'monthspinner',
                        value: Ext.Date.format(startDate,'M, Y')
                    }]
                }]
```

IE is populating the initial value. But just shows mm/dd/yyyy in chrome.

I am getting this error in console.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined
The specified value 'Apr, 2015' does not conform to the required format, 'yyyy-MM-dd'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `startDate` ?

Comment: var startDate = new Date();
startDate.setTime(startDate.getTime() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));